# Communicate with POS terminal via PHP

Tags: php, terminal, point-of-sale

Any idea how can PHP communicate with POS terminal? Communicate = read data, read status, write data (send amount that the customer have to pay).

The main idea is at the end all that the customer have to do is writing his PIN and push the OK button.

PHP and the POST terminal are connected in the same network. The POS terminal can be connected to the Linux machine with serial cable if this is necessary.

Comment: I doubt there's any standard for communication with POS terminals. Can you be more specific about which brand and model you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it.

Fox example, using the serial port.

I guarantee you that if you ask the company provider of the POS device, you can get the programmer reference, in order to know a comm. protocol using the serial port.

First of all ask the provider.